# Postgres - character varying = integer

Tags: java, sqlite, postgresql, ormlite

I try change db from SQLite to PostgreSQL. Some queries return "character varying = integer".

OrmLite entity (subscription entity):

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "subscription")
public class Subscription {
    public static final String SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "id";
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
    private int subscriptionId;

    public static final String BUYER = "buyer";
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = BUYER)
    private BuyerUser buyer;

    public static final String SHOP = "shop";
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = SHOP)
    private Shop shop;
}
```

Shop entity:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "shop")
public class Shop {
    public static final String SHOP_ID_FIELD = "id";
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, allowGeneratedIdInsert = true, columnName = SHOP_ID_FIELD)
    private int shopId;

    public static final String SHOP_NAME_FIELD = "shop_name";
    @DatabaseField(columnName = SHOP_NAME_FIELD)
    private String shop_name;
}
```

Shop id type is int, but in pgAdmin:

```
CREATE TABLE subscription
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    buyer character varying(255),
    shop character varying(255),
    CONSTRAINT subscription_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Shop foreign field type is char. What is wrong?

Comment: *Some queries return "character varying = integer"*. Er, what? What's the *full error message text*?

Comment: org.postgresql.util.psqlexception Error: operator does not exist: character varying = integer

Comment: @WingedPanther I do not understand what is the relation with the problem

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault. The field type was really char.